# Can't attach image in an image tag with nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

Despite following this [example](https://community.nodemailer.com/using-embedded-images/), I can not attach an image to my e-mail the way I'd like to.

What happens:

[image: The received e-mail]

The tag itself is there, it's the picture that can not load. However, it is still attached to the e-mail:

[image: An attached scalable vector graphic]

The code, that is used to send this message is:

```
// ...

var mail_message = "...<img alt=\"Nemalp\" src=\"cid:nemalp\"/>..."; // It is outside the function.

// ...

var mailOptions = {
    from: '"Nemalp" <_______@nemalp.com>',
    to: recipent,
    subject: mail_title,
    html: mail_message,
    attachments: [{ filename: "nemalp.svg", path: __dirname + "/assets/images/website/nemalp.svg/", cid: "nemalp" }]
};
```

The attached image can be downloaded and used but it's not at the place I want it to be. I'd like to have it attached to the `<img/>` tag, rather than just the e-mail itself. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to upload the image on your server or somewhere else and then in the mail html just directly use the image link as src.

```
var mail_message = "...<img alt=\"Nemalp\" src="image url"/>...";
```

Comment: That was an option, but it turns out it was because I used a scalable vector graphic. It has to be an actual image. Weird.